# What actually happens in C++ with function parameters?

Tags: c++, function, parameter-passing

I have been learning C++ for the past couple of months. I know with functions your first declare parameters like so:

```
int myFunc(int funcVar);
```

and then you can pass in an integer variable to that function like so:

```
int x = 5;

myFunc(x);
```

When passing an argument to a function I would usually think of it like assigning and copying the value of x into the parameter of myFunc, which in C++ would look like this:

```
funcVar = x;
```

However, I noticed when declaring functions which have parameters of references (or pointers):

```
int myFunc(int & funcVar);
```

that I can either pass in the variable x to myFunc:

```
myFunc(x);
```

which would look like (in my mind):

```
&funcVar = x;
```

or you can pass in an actual reference as the argument

```
int & rX = x;

myFunc(rX);
```

and the function would work as well which with my thinking would look like this statement in C++

```
int & funcVar = rX
```

which would not make sense assigning a reference to a reference. My question is then how does the compiler actually load in arguments in a function? Should I not think of it like assigning the value of the variable to the parameter of the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call a function, each parameter of the function is **initialized** (not assigned). The rules for this are the same as the rules for any other copy-initialization. So if you have

```
int myFunc(int funcVar);
int x = 5;
myFunc(x);
```

then `funcVar` is **initialized** as though by a statement like this:

```
int funcVar = x;
```

and if you have

```
int myFunc(int & funcVar);
myFunc(x);
int & rX = x;
myFunc(rX);
```

then `funcVar` is **initialized** (and **not assigned**) as though by statements like this:

```
int & funcVar = x;
int & funcVar = rX;
```

The initialization of a reference binds it to the object or function denoted by the initializer. The second initialization does make sense---the *expression* `rX` denotes the *object* `x` because `rX` is a reference bound to `x`. Therefore, initializing a reference with `rX` has the same effect as initializing a reference with `x`.

Comment: Okay, my question is then what's the difference between assigned and initialized? Doesn't the statement  int & funcVar = x  assign the value of x to funcVar?

Comment: @jason assignment will execute the asssigment operator for that object. Initiallization allocates memory for the object and constructors execute.

Comment: @Jason For references, the difference is crucial. Initializing a reference binds it to an object. Assigning a reference assigns to the object the reference is bound to (it doesn't reseat the reference).

Comment: Okay, I guess in my mind I just though of initializing as any statement like  int x;  vs assigning which would be anything where the (=) operator was used.

Answer (score 1):

Let us make easy code and disassemble.

```
int by_value(int x) { return x; }
int by_reference(int &x) { return x; }
int by_pointer(int *x) { return *x; }

int main()
{
    int x = 1;

    by_value(x);
    by_reference(x);
    by_pointer(&x);

    return 0;
}
```

`$ g++ -g -O0 a.cpp ; objdump -dS a.out`

In my environment (x86_64, g++ (SUSE Linux) 4.8.3 20140627), result is as following.
(full text is here http://ideone.com/Z5G8yz)

```
00000000004005dd <_Z8by_valuei>:

int by_value(int x) { return x; }
  4005dd:       55                      push   %rbp
  4005de:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  4005e1:       89 7d fc                mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
  4005e4:       8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
  4005e7:       5d                      pop    %rbp
  4005e8:       c3                      retq   

00000000004005e9 <_Z12by_referenceRi>:
int by_reference(int &x) { return x; }
  4005e9:       55                      push   %rbp
  4005ea:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  4005ed:       48 89 7d f8             mov    %rdi,-0x8(%rbp)
  4005f1:       48 8b 45 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
  4005f5:       8b 00                   mov    (%rax),%eax
  4005f7:       5d                      pop    %rbp
  4005f8:       c3                      retq   

00000000004005f9 <_Z10by_pointerPi>:
int by_pointer(int *x) { return *x; }
  4005f9:       55                      push   %rbp
  4005fa:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  4005fd:       48 89 7d f8             mov    %rdi,-0x8(%rbp)
  400601:       48 8b 45 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
  400605:       8b 00                   mov    (%rax),%eax
  400607:       5d                      pop    %rbp
  400608:       c3                      retq   

0000000000400609 <main>:

int main()
{
  400609:       55                      push   %rbp
  40060a:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  40060d:       48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
        int x = 1;
  400611:       c7 45 fc 01 00 00 00    movl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)

        by_value(x);
  400618:       8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
  40061b:       89 c7                   mov    %eax,%edi
  40061d:       e8 bb ff ff ff          callq  4005dd <_Z8by_valuei>
        by_reference(x);
  400622:       48 8d 45 fc             lea    -0x4(%rbp),%rax
  400626:       48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  400629:       e8 bb ff ff ff          callq  4005e9 <_Z12by_referenceRi>
        by_pointer(&x);
  40062e:       48 8d 45 fc             lea    -0x4(%rbp),%rax
  400632:       48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  400635:       e8 bf ff ff ff          callq  4005f9 <_Z10by_pointerPi>

        return 0;
  40063a:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
}
```

by_reference(x) is as same as by_pointer(&x) !

Comment: Thank you very much for the assembly language representation. I don't yet fully understand how to read assembly but once I do you can be sure I'll be referring back to this answer!

Answer (score 0):

It makes perfect sense to assign a reference to another reference (when first defining it, i.e. at initialization), and that's what actually happens. A reference is just an alias, so when you assign a reference to another reference you are just saying that the first one aliases the one you assigned. Example

```
int x = 42;
int& rx = x;
int& ry = rx;
++ry;
std::cout << x; // displays 43
```

<kbd>[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8eed6e296038db7f)</kbd>